# How to connect Sqlite database to c# wpf application? And how does deployment work?

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I want to connect my Sqlite database to my C# WPF desktop application. How can i do that in the most efficient way? And i want to know about what happens to that db connection when i want to deploy a setup and want to use this application in another computer?(Will that db connection work in other computers?)

Answer (score 0):

Here is link where is it explain in detail how to use sqlite in c#.

https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_data/using-sqlite-in-a-c-application.html.

Db connection will work on other computer if deploy packages required for sqlite.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But i have to not use directory of db file when connecting am i correct? Because that db file may not be in that exact directory in another computer. I can't quite put my finger on it. I hope you understood my  issue. Thanks again.

Comment: if your directory of db file is not fix then you have to give option to choose file in your application before using it.